# Graphics3D artifact in Mathematica 10.1 64bit Home Edition - Windows 7?

Tags: graphics3d

Please confirm if you face the same issue in your system (In gnu-linux it is working fine).

Notice the right and bottom lines - they appear for some reason in every `Graphics3D` routine (Included of course `Plot3D`).

```
Graphics3D[{
  Yellow, Opacity[0.9], PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Faces"], 
  Green, Opacity[0.9], PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]}, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ImagePadding -> 0, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]

How can I get rid off the extra lines? I tried with the options inspector but I had no luck.

**Update:**

Although there is not yet confirmation on a possible bug I implemented a workaround trimming the image. I hope it will be useful for someone.

```
trim[image_,tx_: 10,ty_: 10]:=Module[{x,y},{x,y}=ImageDimensions@image;
ImageTrim[image,{{0+tx,0+ty},{x-tx,0+ty},{0+tx,y-ty},{x-tx,y-ty}}]]
```

Comment: I don't get it in 64 bit Windows 8. If it's windows, it's version dependent.

Comment: Please don't use the bug tag on your own questions.  Due to many mistags in the past, the agreed procedure is that it will be added by another person than the original poster, after others have confirmed it.

Comment: I don't get it with OS X 10.10.4, Mma 10.1.0.

Comment: Could this be also dependent on your graphics drivers?

Comment: Οκ thanks @Szabolcs about the bug notation issue. I don't think so it is a graphics card issue. I exported it in as an image and show it in another machine. The lines are still there. I converted to .m script - same output.

Comment: Do you get it only after exporting or do you get it on-screen?  Do you export with `Export` or using the GUI (they are known to produce differing results)?

Comment: I am getting it on both. I export with `Export`

Comment: I don't get those extra lines with 10.1 on Windows 7, both 64bit. So I think it is not a general problem with that version on Windows 7...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: @m_goldberg maybe I should report this to Wolfram Research attaching a screenshot? Probably there is some problem with rendering on specific drivers.

Comment: could it be some kind of post-evaluation function that has attached itself to Graphics3D outputs that puts them in `Pane`? i don't remember what the commands are but the setting might be somewhere in `AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[]]`. Actually, if this is the case it should be visible if you `// FullForm` the graphics3D output.

Comment: I am also running 10.1.0 on Windows 7 x64 and I do not have this problem.

Comment: When/Using which program do you see these lines? If you see these after opening the file with *Windows Live Photo Gallery* you have nothing to worry about, as these lines aren't part of the image, but added by *Windows Live Photo Gallery* to show you the margins of the image. They disappear if you zoom in.

Comment: Unfortunately the lines is not a zoom issue. They appear also on simple plots (like `Plot3D[....` and the `Export` returns images with the refferenced lines...